# How to install a software on my linux box when I don't have root access (sudo)?

Tags: software-installation, non-root-user, youtube-dl

I have a Debian server which is a "shared server" so I don't have root access but I want to install youtube-dl on it. Is it possible to install it some other way? Like it only accessing current directory or other limitations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install `youtube-dl` through `linuxbrew`

Install `linuxbrew`:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install)"
PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
```

Add the line `export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"` to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"' >>~/.bashrc
```

Install `youtube-dl`:

```
brew install youtube-dl
youtube-dl -U
```

Comment: Thanks! Your method works but I'm still curious to know why enabling Chmod 777 on my directory didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Just interpolate from the [documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme).

With `curl`:

```
mkdir ~/bin
curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o ~/bin/youtube-dl
chmod 0750 ~/bin/youtube-dl
```

Or with `wget`:

```
mkdir ~/bin
wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O ~/bin/youtube-dl
chmod 0750 ~/bin/youtube-dl
```

Note its [requirements](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/).

> It requires the Python interpreter (2.6, 2.7, or 3.2+).

If this a work server, know in advance whether you are permitted to install *and* stream.

Comment: I went to my temp directory and made a directory there for youtube-dl but when I run the curl or wget command, it says "/yt: Read-only file system"

Comment: I've installed WordPress on it, doesn't that mean I have write permission?

Also that mount | grep home returned nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /download/path/
chmod u+rx /download/path/youtube-dl
```

Make sure you have access to the `/download/path/`

Comment: Change path you want, for path you have execute and write permissions on!

Comment: I went to my temp directory and made a directory there for youtube-dl but when I run the curl or wget command, it says "/yt: Read-only file system"

Comment: Is it `/yt: Read-only..` or `/tmp/yt: Read-only...` and can you post the output of `mount | grep rw`

Comment: it's /yt: Read-only..

and that mount command returned nothing. Please note that I've installed WordPress on this box.

Comment: It is `sudo mount | grep rw`.Do you have any directory to which you have write access to? Any `/home` directory.

Comment: I don't have sudo as I don't have root access. How can I determine and find if I have any directory with write access?

Comment: Chmod won't work. I went to the hosting's web site and through a web interface assigned 777 on the folder but still get the same error.